# Обиняк - это что?

Tags: стилистика

Вот еще слово непонятное - обиняк.   
Словари тоже очень  путано объясняют.  
Разговор без обиняков - это какой? И как он соотносится с "нелицеприятным"?

Comment: А какие еще значения слова "обиняк", кроме 'намек', 'недомолвка', Вы встречали в словарях?
И что, простите, Вы подразумеваете под соотношением с "нелицеприятным"? Разговор нелицеприятный или обиняк?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обиняк - недомолвка, намек. "Разговор без обиняков" - откровенный, на чистоту.
А вот насчет "нелицеприятного"...
Тут бы с этим "нелицеприятным" разобраться... Я к тому сейчас не готов, ибо для именя это тоже вопрос непростой. В любом случае [разговор] "без обиняков" и "нелицеприятный" если синонимы, то весьма слабые. При том, что оба можно назвать "откровенными", смысл у этой "откровенности" разный.

Answer (score 4):

> Разговор без обиняков - это какой? И
> как он соотносится с "нелицеприятным"?

Это не синонимы.
Разговаривать без обиняков — это называть при разговоре вещи *своими именами*, то есть отставив в сторону деликатность вообще и жертвуя тактичностью, а порой даже прибегая и действуя в рамках разумного и достаточного цинизма [*здесь смайл*]. Окрашенным субъективностью, конечно, личное мнение остаётся всегда. Мотивы и цели такого разговора — выговориться, если уж не донести до собеседника, высказать без оглядки на возможные последствия свои откровенные мнения и взгляды.
Нелицеприятный разговор — это разговор без пристрастий, разговор, в котором факты и суждения **не** взвешиваются и не выбираются и не опускаются в зависимости от их направленности и причастности с определёнными **лицами**.

Допускаю, что может быть разговор без обиняков с отстаиванием правоты какого-то лица (из чувства, например, личного уважения);  такой разговор вряд ли можно было бы назвать нелицеприятным. Напротив, он именно лицеприятный, а по форме без обиняков.

Comment: >Нелицеприятный разговор — это разговор без пристрастий,  
  
Сдается мне, это уже четвертое толкование, существенное отличающееся от всех предыдущих.

"У Путина с Обамой (ну или с Кадыровым, Собяниным, Шойгу) состоялся нелицеприятный разговор". Это "в котором факты и суждения не взвешиваются"? Мдя...  

С обиняками - согласен.

Answer (score 4):

Разговор без обиняков – разговор  прямой, открытый,  честный, без намеков и недомолвок.  Он обычно содержит  такую  правду, которая неприятна собеседнику.  Эту правду можно сказать по-дружески, а можно жестко и обидно. В последнем случае разговор без обиняков становится нелицеприятным.

НЕБОЛЬШОЕ ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ.
Если речь идет о разговоре, то разговор без обиняков и нелицеприятный разговор достаточно близки по значению, так как разговор без обиняков вряд ли назовешь приятным для собеседников. А вот "отвечать нелицеприятно" - это уж точно отвечать недружественно.

Answer (score 3):

В старой (да и новой) литературе часто встречается деепричастие с отрицанием : **не обинуясь** :

> Максим Соколов. Генрих Гиммлер и общечеловеки (2002) // «Известия», 2002.03.27 Обжегшись на молоке, человечеству отныне следует дуть на воду и, **не обинуясь никакими лишними формальностями, давить гада в зародыше.**

Начальная форма глагола - **обиноваться**. Даль объясняет :

> ОБИНОВАТЬСЯ
> обануться (об и **иной**) церк. колебаться,
> сомневаться, недоверять, опасаться двоякого,
> неверного исхода. Аще обинется, если
> усомнится;
> || церк. и поныне: скрывать, таить,
> умалчивать из опасения;
> || говорить загадочно, не прямо, намеками,
> притчами, иносказанием. Говори не обинуясь,
> чем недоволен? Ты обинуешься, а у меня нет
> догадки.
> Обиновение ср. дл. обинутие однократн.
> сомнение, двусмысленная дума;
> || **обход, минованье чего, и потому**
> || **лицеприятие, пристрастие.**
> Обиняк м. намек, иносказание, обоюдность
> речи, двусмысленность, загадочное
> объяснение. Не говори обиняком, говори
> прямиком. Тонок обиняк, да сквозит. Не люблю
> обиняков. Закинуть обиняка. Под спудом и не
> обиняк век пролежит, не скажется..
> Обинячный, обиняковый намек, - шпилька.
> Обинячить , говорить обиняками, отпускать
> обиняки...

Обинячить ~ "обиначить", надвое сказать - то ли так, то ли эдак. Что-то типа скрытого упрека : "Наш начальник с похмелья на работу никогда еще не приходил!" (завуалированный смысл : если накануне Иван Иваныч выпил лишнего, он просто не появляется, находя уважительную причину)

Когда человек говорит обиняками, обходит острые углы стороной - значит, он **не хочет нелицеприятного разговора** и прямых обвинений в адрес собеседника или третьего лица.
Обиняк - лицеприятное выражение, дипломатический оборот речи. Не в лоб человека бьют тяжелыми упреками, а с мягкими оговорочками, с возможностью оправдания.

Answer (score 2):

А я слышала забавный детский вариант этого слова и не раз. Оно звучит как "обиДняк". Я так поняла, что "без обиДняков" значит следующее: если что-то из услышанного в последующем разговоре (сообщении) окажется неприятным,  то чур не обижаться. )))

Answer (score 1):

Марина Королева:

Уж сколько раз мы говорили о неистребимой нашей любви к красивым словам! В самой этой любви ничего страшного нет, но она, как правило, бывает омрачена: значение красивого слова не всегда понимают правильно, а значит, и используют не всегда по назначению. И опять-таки: не так уж страшно, если это случилось один раз. Но бывают слова поистине несчастные, которые изо дня в день появляются не там, где надо. Ошибка становится привычной. А все она, любовь к красному словцу...

Вот так, изо дня в день наталкиваюсь я на слово "нелицеприятный". Кто скажет о нелицеприятном событии, кто - о нелицеприятном случае, кто - о нелицеприятных фактах, а кто - о нелицеприятном портрете собеседника. Журналисты полюбили это слово, им нравится, судя по всему, как оно звучит. При этом большинство из них уверено, что "нелицеприятный" - синоним, заменитель "неприятного".

Ничего подобного! "Нелицеприятный" и "неприятный", несмотря на их внешнее сходство, совершенно разные слова, и я постараюсь вам это сейчас доказать. Собственно, это нетрудно, достаточно заглянуть в любой толковый словарь, например, в Толково-словообразовательный. "Нелицеприятный", сообщают нам, - это "беспристрастный"!

"Беспристрастный" - не основанный на лицеприятии. И вот тут уже потребуются небольшие пояснения. Дело в том, что "лицеприятие" - слово устарелое, оно сейчас почти не используется. Лице приятие - пристрастное отношение к кому-нибудь или чему-нибудь. Лицеприятный, соответственно, - основанный на лице приятии. Отсюда один шаг до нелицеприятного, то есть БЕСпристрастного. Непредубежденного. Объективного. Справедливого! Даль приводит и другие синонимы нелицеприятного: правдивый, праведный, правосудный.

Ну и при чем же здесь "неприятный"?.. Конечно, беспристрастное и справедливое не всегда бывает приятным, но не до такой же степени!

Comment: Да, спасибо, это правильно.
Но с этим словом "нелицеприятный" еще хуже, чем тут изложено. 
Помимо указанных вариантов понимания (правильного и выдуманного) фиксируется еще парочка. "Нелицеприятный - неприятный лицом" и "Нелицеприятный - общий, единый, не тот, что принимается конкретным лицом".  Оба, как следует из императивного мнения М.К., надо признать неправильными. Хотя второе мне кажется просто анекдотическим, а вот первое не таким уж абсурдным...